# Laravel cache remaining TTL

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-5

I am looking for a way to access the remaining TTL of a redis key value pair via laravel. I don't mind using either the `Cache` or `Redis` facades (or anything else for that matter).

[In the api](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.html) I can only see how to return the default TTL - `getDefaultCacheTime()`.

I want to find the remaining TTL.

For reference, the redis terminal command is `TTL mykey`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's a `command` method on the `Illuminate\Redis\Database` class you can simply run :

```
Redis::command('TTL', ['yourKey']);
```

This is [documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/redis#basic-usage).

Answer (score 4):

Turns out (with the recent versions of laravel anyway) that you can use redis commands and they will be converted using magic methods. So you can simply use

```
Redis::ttl('yourKey');
```